# package.json - how to set default value of variable in windows

Tags: npm-scripts

In Linux you can use the following syntax to set the default value of a variable in the package.json file: `try=${myEnvVariable:"defaultValue"}`

How do you do this using the syntax for window %varaibelName% ? This does not work:
`try=%myEnvVariable:"defaultValue"%`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No solution for default in Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

You can define a script in the `scripts` section of the `package.json` like this

```
"scripts": {
  "set-myenv": "npm config set myEnvVariable <yourDefuaultValue>"
}
```

To use this in another script, you can chain scripts with `&&`

```
"scripts": {
  "set-myenv-and-execute": "npm config set myEnvVariable <yourDefuaultValue> && another command --some-option %npm_config_myEnvVariable%"
}
```

Here, the second script (after `&&`) has the `--some-option` option set with the default value of `myEnvVariable` through `%npm_config_myEnvVariable%`

Then, you can execute this script in the command line either by providing a value to `myEnvVariable`

```
> npm run set-myenv-and-execute --myEnvVariable=someValue
```

or without providing a value

```
> npm run set-myenv-and-execute
```

Here it uses the default value.

Comment: I will try that. looks promising.